# ZFS - HDD performance strongly varies in 3-way-mirror among vendors

Tags: hard-drive, performance, zfs, trim

### Prerequisite

We have a FreeNAS System with a Pool consiting of 5x"3-way-mirror". The disks per mirror are from different vendors but with the same "on-paper" performace-characteristics.

Pool-Layout:

```
Tank0
  mirror-0
    Western Digital WDC WD20SPZX (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
    Seagate ST2000LM015 (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
    Toshiba HDWL120 (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
  mirror-1
    Western Digital WDC WD20SPZX (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
    Seagate ST2000LM015 (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
    Toshiba HDWL120 (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
  mirror-2
    Western Digital WDC WD20SPZX (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
    Seagate ST2000LM015 (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
    Toshiba HDWL120 (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
  mirror-3
    Western Digital WDC WD20SPZX (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
    Seagate ST2000LM015 (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
    Toshiba HDWL120 (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
  mirror-4
    Western Digital WDC WD20SPZX (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
    Seagate ST2000LM015 (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
    Toshiba HDWL120 (2TB, 128MB Cache, 5400 RPM)
  logs
    mirror-5
       Seagate ST200FM0002 (200GB SAS SSD)
       Seagate ST200FM0002 (200GB SAS SSD)
  cache
    Samsung 850 PRO (512GB SATA SSD)
```

The 3 different drive vendors per mirror where chosen to minimize the risk of failing specific models of drives. WD and Seagate drives were inserted at creation time of the mirror, Toshiba drives have been added later to form a 3-way-mirror.

All drives are attached on a backplane of a HP SE326M1-Server. The backplane itself is atached to a HP H220 HBA flashed with IT-Mode Firmware.

ZFS is able to interact with each drive directly without any raid-cards.

**Smart-Values of Drives**

*Western Digital*

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD20SPZX-00CRAT0
Serial Number:    WD-WXA1E17A5SPC
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 65db69aed
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Apr 24 13:04:40 2019 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (21120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 368) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       7047
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   111   109   000    Old_age   Always       -       36
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         2         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

*Seagate*

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 2.5 5400
Device Model:     ST2000LM015-2E8174
Serial Number:    WDZBHCXK
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0acdec7df
Firmware Version: SDM1
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Apr 24 13:05:23 2019 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 331) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   078   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       57137976
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       4
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   086   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       426983688
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       7054 (57 92 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       4
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   067   064   040    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 23/36)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       15
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   033   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (0 23 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       7054 (68 231 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       74035391620
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       65426356249
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         2         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

*Toshiba*

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     TOSHIBA HDWL120
Serial Number:    88K6P0OYT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 8b2409181
Firmware Version: JT000A
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Apr 24 13:09:44 2019 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 322) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1621
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       3577
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       16896
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 24/34)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       3540
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       268
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

### camcontrol output

```
camcontrol identify <dev>
```

*WD*

```
pass6: <WDC WD20SPZX-00CRAT0 01.01A01> ACS-3 ATA SATA 3.x device
pass6: 300.000MB/s transfers, Command Queueing Enabled

protocol              ATA/ATAPI-10 SATA 3.x
device model          WDC WD20SPZX-00CRAT0
firmware revision     01.01A01
serial number         WD-WX91E17FJNXD
WWN                   50014ee6086142a7
cylinders             16383
heads                 16
sectors/track         63
sector size           logical 512, physical 4096, offset 0
LBA supported         268435455 sectors
LBA48 supported       3907029168 sectors
PIO supported         PIO4
DMA supported         WDMA2 UDMA6
media RPM             5400

Feature                      Support  Enabled   Value           Vendor
read ahead                     yes      yes
write cache                    yes      yes
flush cache                    yes      yes
overlap                        no
Tagged Command Queuing (TCQ)   no       no
Native Command Queuing (NCQ)   yes              32 tags
NCQ Queue Management           no
NCQ Streaming                  no
Receive & Send FPDMA Queued    no
SMART                          yes      yes
microcode download             yes      yes
security                       yes      no
power management               yes      yes
advanced power management      yes      no      254/0xFE
automatic acoustic management  no       no
media status notification      no       no
power-up in Standby            yes      no
write-read-verify              no       no
unload                         yes      yes
general purpose logging        yes      yes
free-fall                      no       no
Data Set Management (DSM/TRIM) yes
DSM - max 512byte blocks       yes              10
DSM - deterministic read       yes              any value
Host Protected Area (HPA)      no
```

*Seagate*

```
pass4: <ST2000LM015-2E8174 SDM1> ACS-3 ATA SATA 3.x device
pass4: 300.000MB/s transfers, Command Queueing Enabled

protocol              ATA/ATAPI-10 SATA 3.x
device model          ST2000LM015-2E8174
firmware revision     SDM1
serial number         WDZBHCXK
WWN                   5000c500acdec7df
cylinders             16383
heads                 16
sectors/track         63
sector size           logical 512, physical 4096, offset 0
LBA supported         268435455 sectors
LBA48 supported       3907029168 sectors
PIO supported         PIO4
DMA supported         WDMA2 UDMA6
media RPM             5400

Feature                      Support  Enabled   Value           Vendor
read ahead                     yes      yes
write cache                    yes      yes
flush cache                    yes      yes
overlap                        no
Tagged Command Queuing (TCQ)   no       no
Native Command Queuing (NCQ)   yes              32 tags
NCQ Queue Management           no
NCQ Streaming                  no
Receive & Send FPDMA Queued    no
SMART                          yes      yes
microcode download             yes      yes
security                       yes      no
power management               yes      yes
advanced power management      yes      no      0/0x00
automatic acoustic management  no       no
media status notification      no       no
power-up in Standby            yes      no
write-read-verify              yes      no      0/0x0
unload                         yes      yes
general purpose logging        yes      yes
free-fall                      no       no
Data Set Management (DSM/TRIM) no
Host Protected Area (HPA)      yes      no      3907029168/3907029168
HPA - Security                 no
```

*Toshiba*

```
pass16: <TOSHIBA HDWL120 JT000A> ACS-3 ATA SATA 3.x device
pass16: 150.000MB/s transfers, Command Queueing Enabled

protocol              ATA/ATAPI-10 SATA 3.x
device model          TOSHIBA HDWL120
firmware revision     JT000A
serial number         88K6P0O0T
WWN                   50000398b240915f
cylinders             16383
heads                 16
sectors/track         63
sector size           logical 512, physical 4096, offset 0
LBA supported         268435455 sectors
LBA48 supported       3907029168 sectors
PIO supported         PIO4
DMA supported         WDMA2 UDMA5
media RPM             5400

Feature                      Support  Enabled   Value           Vendor
read ahead                     yes      yes
write cache                    yes      yes
flush cache                    yes      yes
overlap                        no
Tagged Command Queuing (TCQ)   no       no
Native Command Queuing (NCQ)   yes              32 tags
NCQ Queue Management           no
NCQ Streaming                  no
Receive & Send FPDMA Queued    no
SMART                          yes      yes
microcode download             yes      yes
security                       yes      no
power management               yes      yes
advanced power management      yes      yes     128/0x80
automatic acoustic management  no       no
media status notification      no       no
power-up in Standby            yes      no
write-read-verify              yes      no      0/0x0
unload                         yes      yes
general purpose logging        yes      yes
free-fall                      no       no
Data Set Management (DSM/TRIM) no
Host Protected Area (HPA)      yes      no      3907029168/3907029168
HPA - Security                 no
```

### Symptoms

The pool itself is stable for months. But we observed massive performance-differences on vendor drives.

- Disk-Busy: The WD-Drives are busy most of the time (95-100% Disk Busy) while the others (Seagate and Toshiba) have a max of 30%.
  [image: WD Disk Busy][image: Seagate Disk Busy][image: Toshiba Disk Busy]
- Disk Latency: WD Drives show latencys between 2000 and 8000 msec. for Writes and Deletes while the others (Seagate and Toshiba) are in Ranges of 20-50msec. [image: Western Digital Disk Latency][image: Seagate Disk Latency][image: Toshiba Disk Latency]
- All Drives of the same vendors behave simillar.

  - All WD drives in this system show bad performance. Graphs are almost identical
  - All Seagate and Toshiba Drives show almost identical performance data among thier vendors.
  - Seagate and Toshiba behave almost the same with very slight differences.

**Question(s)**

- Why do the WD Drives have such bad performance in this Setup.
- Did i miss something in choosing "same drive characteristics"?

  - yes i did: Only WD supports DSM/TRIM! [Info about TRIM on WD drives](https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/25185)
- Is there a setting for WD-Drives to behave better?
- Why does the WD drive support DSM/TRIM while the others do not?

  - Is there a way to disable that feature to test without?

Comment: "Busy" and "high latency" are related. One thing that comes to mind is that the WD drives maybe have less real (or usable) cache than 128MB. I guess one should be able to determine the amount of cache by isolating one WD drive, and do a few read/write tests - performance should drop as soon as the cache is full.

Comment: @dirkt When mentioning cache i thought about this. What could be the difference among the drives? All 3 drives use "Drive Managed SMR" (Shingled Magnetic Recording). Then i thought about differences in SMR logic but could not find docs about specific models. Then i used camcontrol to get the drive features. i found 2 differences: 1) "write-read-verify" - WD supports it, but it is disabled. 2) "Data Set Management (DSM/TRIM) which is supported only by the WD drives. The graphs show, that only WD drives have "Delete" operations while ohters have not. Why should a HDD support TRIM?

Comment: I'd sort of distrust published specs; they may be tuned to look more impressive than they are, or there may be plain mistakes in them. In doubt, test; it should be possible to figure out some performance tests that somehow measure available cache (or other things that could be different).

Comment: *Why does the WD drive support DSM/TRIM / Why should a HDD support TRIM?* - It is because your WD drive is a SMR drive: https://products.wdc.com/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2579-810249.pdf (search the model number). SMR drives need trimming due to performance issues, so I wouldn't recommend disabling it. Google "SMR vs CMR drives" and "SMR drives trim" for more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CAUSE: The Western Digital Drives support TRIM**

Other than Seagate and Toshiba the WD-drive supports TRIM: `Data Set Management (DSM/TRIM) yes`

ZFS on FreeBSD (FreeNAS) supports TRIM too. The WD drives have plenty to do tiding up deleted Data.

---

**SOLUTION: Disable TRIM**

1) My attempt to disable TRIM on the drives itself at runtime ended in a kernel panic. **Do this at your own risk!**

```
sysctl kern.cam.da.6.delete_method=DISABLE
```

---

2) **Disabling TRIM for ZFS** did succeed, but leaves my Cache-SSD without TRIM.

Goto FreeNAS - System - Tunables and click "Add Tuneable"

```
Variable: vfs.zfs.trim.enabled
Value: 0
Type: Loader
Enabled: checked
```

After rebooting ZFS does not TRIM anymore. The storage is reactig much quicker. "Disk Busy" stays at a high level, but **"Disk Latency" dropped from Seconds to milliseconds!**

"Pending I/O requests" dropped from avg. 130 to not more than 20.

The Storage itself **feels much more agile**.
[image]
[image]

Edit: last Scrub took about **11 hours** while the one before took **24 days**.